# Error while implementing take for a Stream

Tags: scala, stream, take

I was trying to solve Exercise 2 from [Functional Programming in Scala](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/). The question is as follows:

> EXERCISE 2: Write a function take for returning the first n elements
>   of a Stream.
>         ￼def take(n: Int): Stream[A]

My solution is as follows:

```
    import Stream._
    trait Stream[+A]{
            def uncons:Option[(A,Stream[A])]
            def isEmpty:Boolean = uncons.isEmpty
            def toList:List[A] = {
                    val listBuffer = new collection.mutable.ListBuffer[A]
                    @annotation.tailrec
                    def go(str:Stream[A]):List[A] = str uncons match {
                            case Some((a,tail)) => listBuffer += a;go(tail)
                            case _ => listBuffer.toList
                    }
                    go(this)
            }

            def take(n:Int):Stream[A] = uncons match {
                    case Some((hd,tl)) if (n > 0) => cons(hd,tl.take(n-1))
                    case _ => Stream()
            }
    }

   object Stream{
        def empty[A]:Stream[A] = new Stream[A]{def uncons = None}
        def cons[A](hd: => A,tl: => Stream[A]):Stream[A] = new Stream[A]{
                lazy val uncons = Some((hd,tl))
        }
        def apply[A](as: A*):Stream[A] = {
                if(as.isEmpty) empty else
                        cons(as.head,apply(as.tail: _ *))
        }
}
```

I store this as Stream2.scala and then from the REPL I execute the following:

```
:load Stream2.scala
```

When the REPL tries to load my script, it barfs with the following errors:

scala> :load Stream2.scala

```
Loading Stream2.scala...
import Stream._
<console>:24: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Stream[A]
 required: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[?]
            case Some((hd,tl)) if (n > 0) => cons(hd,tl.take(n-1))
                                                                ^
<console>:25: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Nothing]
 required: Stream[A]
            case _ => Stream()
                                ^
<console>:11: error: object creation impossible, since method tailDefined in class Stream of type => Boolean is not defined
        def empty[A]:Stream[A] = new Stream[A]{def uncons = None}
                                     ^
<console>:12: error: object creation impossible, since method tailDefined in class Stream of type => Boolean is not defined
        def cons[A](hd: => A,tl: => Stream[A]):Stream[A] = new Stream[A]{
```

Can somebody point out what might be going wrong here?

Comment: Try this outside of the REPL - compile the code using `scalac Stream2.scala`. It can be that the REPL doesn't connect the companion object to the `Stream` trait. Also there seems to be some interference from the standard library `Stream` (which shares the same name as your `Stream`). Compiling outside the REPL may provide longer error messages.

Comment: Or coming to a repl near you, perhaps, :paste file, https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4684

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just place import statement under the Stream trait. It doesn't work cause for Scala compiler you are importing `scala.collection.immutable.Stream`, but not your companion object. And, as it was sad in the comments use `:paste` in console, but paste it in as a hole code, otherwise it won't be a companion object to your trait